# Run arguments in Docker Compose

Tags: docker-compose

I'm trying to run Consul and Registrator with Docker Compose. By hand, I do this:

```
docker run --net=host consul 
docker run --net=host -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock gliderlabs/registrator consul://localhost:8500
```

I have this docker-compose.yml, so far:

```
version: '2'
services:
  consul:
    network_mode: 'host'
    image: consul
  registrator:
    network_mode: 'host'
    volumes:
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock
    depends_on:
     - consul
    image: gliderlabs/registrator
```

But, how can I pass the argument "consul://localhost:8500" to registrator in docker-compose.yml?

Comment: What happens if you run `docker-compose run registrator consul://localhost:8500` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can overwrite the entrypoint. The registrator default entrypoint is:

ENTRYPOINT /bin/registrator

In your docker-compose.yml file you can set:

```
entrypoint: /bin/registrator consul://localhost:8500
```